# does fb:swf run on iphone?

Tags: iphone, flash, ipad, fbml

I have written a facebook page with fb:swf, and today the client asked if it would run on their iphone/ipad. Does this work out of the box?

Comment: As I understand it, fb:swf requires flash ( aka shockwave, aka swf ) so this will never work on iOS devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sir. FB SWF will not run without the plugin which doesn't run on the iPhone and arguably doesn't on any Apple product =/

Answer (score 1):

No.  It still needs the Flash player which *still* isn't supported by Apple on these devices.

It might work on a Jail-Broken iPhone/iPad, but I can't say whether this is the case or not.